# Cant insert into table PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php query...

```
INSERT INTO `demographic2` (id, name, first_name, last_name, link, username, birthday, gender, relationship_status, email, timezone, locale, verified, updated_time) VALUES (845450180, Liam Gallagher, Liam, Gallagher, http://www.facebook.com/lia.co.uk, lia.co.uk, 11/25/1989, male, Single, gal@hotmail.com, 1, en_US, 1, 2012-03-30T21:54:17+0000)
```

I cant see any errors but for some reason the above wont insert data into my table, the schema looks like so...

[image]

Regarding string literals, I have this as my insert query, How would i add the quotes?

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($userInfo));
            $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($userInfo));
            $values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `demographic2` ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Comment: You need to write strings inside quote, like `VALUES ('845450180', 'Liam Gallagher'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try enclosing `', '` as glue into the implode() in the second use, so it becomes:

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($userInfo));
            $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($userInfo));
            $values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `demographic2` ({$columns}) VALUES ('{$values}')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Read about [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) in MySQL. You have to write strings in quotes, eg: `"my text"`.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your string value with `""` or `''`, e.g. `"value"` or `'value'`.

You can also read more about anti-SQL-injection techniques to create an SQL query string better at http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `'SomevarcharOrDatetime'`

```
INSERT INTO `demographic2` 
(
  id, name, 
  first_name, 
  last_name, 
  link, 
  username, 
  birthday, 
  gender, 
  relationship_status, 
  email, 
  timezone, 
  locale, 
  verified, 
  updated_time
) 
VALUES 
(
  845450180, 
  'Liam Gallagher', 
  'Liam', 
  'Gallagher', 
  'http://www.facebook.com/lia.co.uk', 
  'lia.co.uk', 
  '11/25/1989', 
  'male', 
  'Single', 
  'gal@hotmail.com', 
  1, 
  'en_US', 
  1, 
  '2012-03-30T21:54:17+0000'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is quoted.

```
INSERT INTO `demographic2` (id, name, first_name, last_name, link, username, birthday, gender, relationship_status, email, timezone, locale, verified, updated_time)
VALUES (845450180, "Liam Gallagher", "Liam", "Gallagher", "http://www.facebook.com/lia.co.uk", "lia.co.uk", "11/25/1989", "male", "Single", "gal@hotmail.com", "1", "en_US", "1", "2012-03-30T21:54:17+0000")
```

Also, why aren't you using DATE columns for dates (birthday)?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom function to map each value & apply single quote to escaped string.

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($userInfo));
$escaped_values = array_map('escape_inpt_string', array_values($userInfo));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `demographic2` ($columns) VALUES ($values)";

function escape_inpt_string($val) {
  return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."'";
}
```

Cheers!!